# Seaborn Lineplot show custom central line instead of mean

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a dataset that is consisting of three values for each timestep: Once the mean value as well as the lower and upper error bound.

```
name,year,area
test,2017,1.0376800009967053 #mean
test,2017,0.09936810445983806 #lower bound
test,2017,2.118230806622908 #upper bound and so on ...
test,2018,1.0
test,2018,0.13705391957353763
test,2018,2.1881023056535183
test,2019,1.2928531655977922
test,2019,0.17400072775054737
test,2019,3.016064939443665
```

I would like to plot the data so that I get a shaded area between the upper and the lower bound and have a line in between that follows the mean value in the dataset.

I have tried seaborn.lineplot
(https://seaborn.pydata.org/examples/errorband_lineplots.html)
however it calculates the mean of the tree values and so the line is not where the actual mean should be.
Any body got some ideas?
Is it possible to change the way seaborn calculates the central line? (for example to median)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `estimator` keyword of `seaborn.lineplot`. In the [documentation](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.lineplot.html) you find regarding this:

> **estimator : name of pandas method or callable or `None`, optional**
>
> Method for aggregating across multiple observations of the `y` variable at the same `x` level. If `None`, all observations will be drawn.

Default value for `estimator` is `mean`, which explains your observation decribed in the question. So you can define a `lambda` function selecting always the first value of the three values of the same `year`.

```
lambda x: x[0]
```

Using

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.lineplot(x='year', y='area', data=df, estimator=lambda x: x[0], marker='o')
```

gives the plot you want.

[image]

If you want to have the `median` instead, `import numpy as np` before and use `estimator=np.median`.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply, that helped. Only one more question, when I combine it with hue="name" it throws an error, do you know why? (There are more entries in the csv containing different names)

Comment: what error does it throw? Maybe you can file a new question with an updated snapshot of your data

Comment: It starts with "line 663, in agg_series" then multiple errors are thrown. I solved it by plotting multiple times with a for loop. However I needed to reset the index of the table for each iteration with: plotData = df.loc[df['name'] == name]
 plotData = plotData.reset_index(drop=True)